# Cannot create superuser in Django

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I wanted to use email instead of username to login. But while creating superuser I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

**users/view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .forms import CustomUserCreation

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreation
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print (self.request.user)
        return super(HomePage, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**users/models.py**

```
#users/models.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'..')

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
import questions_and_answers
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

fields_ = questions_and_answers.fields
def apply_defaults(cls):
    for name, value in fields_.items():
        setattr(cls, name, models.CharField(default=value[1]))
    return cls

#@apply_defaults
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='0')
    q2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='0')
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True) # changes email to unique and blank to false
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # removes email from REQUIRED_FIELDS
```

**users/forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreation(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
class CustomUserChange(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email',)
```

I am pretty beginner in django, hence no idea what went wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That's because your `CustomUser` class is still using the default `Manager`, which defines the `create_superuser` method and requires a username (it doesn't check the value for `USERNAME_FIELD`, that's only used in the login and authentication backend).

You should override the `Manager` with your own and redefine `create_superuser()`, as shown in [this example in the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). You should also override the `create_user` method.

This is actually described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model)